# What are the Best Ruby videos/Screencasts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the Best Ruby Screencasts/videos to really understand ruby? Which ones would you recommend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com/)
- [Teach Me To Code](http://teachmetocode.com/)
- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)
- [RubyPulse](http://www.rubypulse.com/)
- [Ruby Tapas](http://www.rubytapas.com/)
- [GoRails](https://gorails.com/)

Comment: Don't forget the pragmatic bookshelf, pragprog.com. I especially like "The Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming" by Dave Thomas.

Comment: In that awesome list, unfortunately only Ruby Tapas seems alive, today. I really miss Railscasts from [ryanb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/148722/ryanb)

Comment: True, most of them are gone :-( But then we have Ruby Rogues...

Comment: [Semicolon&Sons](https://www.semicolonandsons.com/series/Inside-The-Muse) are active as of 2020 and focus on more advanced topics in production codebases.

Answer (score 1):

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) is probably one of the best around, and Ryan actively updates it weekly. Gregg Pollack also did a [few](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts). There's also a ton of Ruby related screen casts floating around the internet, whether they're taken from conference talks or self built on youtube.

Comment: -1 : While those sites are good Rails references they do not help (directly) with learning Ruby. Rails != Ruby and in fact knowing Ruby before learning Rails is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com) videos, i really liked them and the guy is very instructive.